# Pytorch lobpcg not working with complex sparse arrays?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

I am currently trying to use Pytorch "lobpcg" to diagonalize a large sparse array using my GPU. The function seems to be working just fine when diagonalizing arrays comprised of real values, yet it returns me somewhat confusing error messages whenever the array contains complex values instead. As a reference I leave here snippets of my code and the error message returned

```
from scipy import sparse
import torch
from torch import lobpcg
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse 
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
#%%
def Torchfy(arr): # storese sparse arrays in gpu
   arr = arr.tocoo() # Converting to "coordinate format" (type of way to store matrix in the GPU)
   # Here we create sparse pythorch tensor feeding in the indices: device was defined in first cell
   arr = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(indices=torch.tensor([arr.row, arr.col]), values=torch.tensor(arr.data), size=arr.shape).to(device)
   return arr
def H_L(xcoor, ycoor, zcoor, b = 1, g1 = 1, g2 = 1, g3 = 1, e = 1, m = 1, hbar = 1):
########################################### Pre Calculations ###############################################
   h2 = hbar ** 2 # hbar sqrd
   c1 = - h2/(2*m) * (g1 + 2.5 * g2) # setting constant for first term
   c2 = g2 * h2 / m # setting constant for second term
   c3 = g3 * h2/(2*m) # setting constant for third term
   e2 = e ** 2 # e-charge sqrd
   eh = e / hbar
   e2h2 = e2 / h2
   y = 0.5 * b * sparse.spdiags(ycoor.reshape(N3), np.array([0]), N3, N3) # repeated, put in diagonal form (N^3,N^3) 
   x = 0.5 * b * sparse.spdiags(xcoor.reshape(N3), np.array([0]), N3, N3) # repeated, put in diagonal form (N^3,N^3) 
   y2 = y ** 2
   x2 = x ** 2
############################################ First Term ####################################################
   lapl = ddxx + ddyy + ddzz # Laplacian
   a_nabl = -1j * eh * (x * ddy - y * ddx)  # A(r) * Nabla, where A generates B = b * \hat{z}
   a2 = e2h2 * (y2 + x2)
   tmp1 = c1 * (- lapl + a_nabl + a2) # summing the terms relevant to tmp1
   tmp1 = sparse.kron(tmp1, np.eye(4)) # No J_i coupling so we consider kron with identity 
############################################ Second Term ###################################################
   kx2 = - ddxx + 1j * eh * y * ddx + e2h2 * y2
   ky2 = - ddyy - 1j * eh * x * ddy + e2h2 * x2
   tmp2 = sparse.kron(kx2, J_x2) + sparse.kron(ky2, J_y2) + sparse.kron(-ddzz, J_z2)
############################################ Third Term #####################################################
   kxky = 0.5 * (- 2 * ddxy - 2 * e2h2 * x * y - 1j * eh *( x * ddx - y * ddy))
   kxkz = 0.5 * (- 2 * ddxz + 1j * eh * y * ddz)
   kykz = 0.5 * (- 2 * ddyz - 1j * eh * x * ddz)
   tmp3 = sparse.kron(kxky, jxjy) + sparse.kron(kxkz, jxjz) + sparse.kron(kykz, jyjz)
   return tmp1 + tmp2 + tmp3
h = H_L(X, Y, Z)
h = Torchfy(h)
# Using the "Locally optimal block preconditioned conjugate gradient method" to obtain the first 10 eigenvalues
# we focus on the lowest ones (i.e. largest = False)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = lobpcg(h, k=10, largest=False)
```

After running the full version of the above code I get the error message: RuntimeError: expected scalar type ComplexDouble but found Float. Is there any fix for this?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
Running h = torch.complex(h.real, h.imag).to(device) I get the error message: NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::view_as_real' with arguments from the 'SparseCPU' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'aten::view_as_real' is only available for these backends: [CPU, Meta, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradHIP, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradIPU, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradVE, AutogradLazy, AutogradMeta, AutogradMTIA, AutogradPrivateUse1, AutogradPrivateUse2, AutogradPrivateUse3, AutogradNestedTensor, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PythonDispatcher].

CPU: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/build/aten/src/ATen/RegisterCPU.cpp:31034 [kernel] Meta: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/build/aten/src/ATen/RegisterMeta.cpp:26824 [kernel] BackendSelect: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/core/BackendSelectFallbackKernel.cpp:3 [backend fallback] Python: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/core/PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:144 [backend fallback] FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/functorch/DynamicLayer.cpp:491 [backend fallback] Functionalize: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/build/aten/src/ATen/RegisterFunctionalization_2.cpp:21384 [kernel] Named: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/core/NamedRegistrations.cpp:7 [backend fallback] Conjugate: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/ConjugateFallback.cpp:21 [kernel] Negative: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/native/NegateFallback.cpp:23 [kernel] ZeroTensor: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/ZeroTensorFallback.cpp:90 [kernel] ADInplaceOrView: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ADInplaceOrViewType_0.cpp:4733 [kernel] AutogradOther: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradCPU: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradCUDA: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradHIP: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradXLA: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradMPS: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradIPU: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradXPU: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradHPU: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradVE: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradLazy: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradMeta: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradMTIA: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradPrivateUse1: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradPrivateUse2: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradPrivateUse3: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] AutogradNestedTensor: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp:15288 [autograd kernel] Tracer: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_4.cpp:12892 [kernel] AutocastCPU: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/autocast_mode.cpp:487 [backend fallback] AutocastCUDA: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/autocast_mode.cpp:354 [backend fallback] FuncTorchBatched: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/functorch/BatchRulesUnaryOps.cpp:82 [kernel] FuncTorchVmapMode: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/functorch/VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:28 [backend fallback] Batched: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:1077 [kernel] VmapMode: fallthrough registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:33 [backend fallback] FuncTorchGradWrapper: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/functorch/TensorWrapper.cpp:210 [backend fallback] PythonTLSSnapshot: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/core/PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:152 [backend fallback] FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/functorch/DynamicLayer.cpp:487 [backend fallback] PythonDispatcher: registered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1682343904035/work/aten/src/ATen/core/PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:148 [backend fallback]